# Code works on JSfiddle but not on my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mppcb/1/ works perfectly there, but when I copy the same codes on my website (http://www.tuivel.com/upload/index.html) it won't work:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="text" name="field1[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field2[]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field3[]">
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="field4[]" id="filename">
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS & jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    function Checksize(){
    var iSize = ($("#filename")[0].files[0].size);
       alert(iSize);
     if (iSize < 2097152.00) 
         { 
        alert("Es menor a 2 megabytes!!!!");
         return true;
         }
       else{
           alert("Es mayor a 2mb!!");
           return false;
           }
    }


function Checkfiles() {
        var fup = document.getElementById('filename');
        var fileName = fup.value;
        var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        var chkext = ext.toLowerCase();
        //var fileSize = fup.size;

    if(chkext=="gif" || chkext=="jpg" || chkext=="jpeg" || chkext=="png") {
        alert("Successfully Uploaded!");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("Upload GIF, PNG, JPG Images only");
        return false;
    }
} 

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            "field1[]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
            "field2[]": {
                required: true,
                url: true
            },
            "field3[]": {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            "field4[]": {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) { // for demo
            var result=Checkfiles();
            var size=Checksize();
            alert(size);
            alert(result);
            if(size==true && result==true) {
                alert("Ya se subió!!!");
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Por algo no pasó!!!");
                return false;
            }

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

I'm also including the jQuery library:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any wonder why is not working for me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What won't work? What does console say? Did you try debugging?

Comment: what happens if you run this on your website? can you post a link?

Comment: If you have firefox with firebug or chrome please press f12 and see if the error console prints any javascript errors.

Comment: Here is on my website: http://www.tuivel.com/upload/index.html

Comment: you're missing the validate plugin. validate is not a method in the standard jquery library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#myform').validate({
```

You didn't use the `validate` plugin on your site, but the author of the jsFiddle did:

[image: jsfiddle validate plugin]

To fix this, simply download the `validate` plugin, then add this in the HTML before your script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/validate/plugin.js"></script>
```

For future reference, you can see all of the included plugins by clicking "external resources" at the left sidebar of the jsFiddle.

Comment: Ahh man, you're a genius. Thank you! just updated check it out! http://www.tuivel.com/upload/index.html

Comment: What other plugins do they include automatically?

Comment: @orb I'm not sure it was automatic; the author of the fiddle may have done it manually.

Comment: @Doorknob. Yeah that was probably it. Good eye Doorknob.